# Where is the logfile located for Xcode Scheme Post-Actions?

Tags: xcode, logging, post-build, xcode-scheme

I am running a script in my Xcode project in the Scheme's Build->Post-actions "Run Script". It runs fine but I would like to see the console output of that script. It doesn't seem to be included in the Log Navigator tab, where can I find this log?

Comment: I see pre-build actions logs in Xcode 14.3.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The output from those scripts doesn't seem to be logged anywhere by default. Your best bet is to manually redirect the output of the script to a known location. For example, add the following as the first line of your script:

```
exec > /tmp/my_log_file.txt 2>&1
```

This will redirect all following output to stdout and stderr to your specified log file.

Comment: For some reason even after adding this, neither the folder or files are visible in the project directory but if I use terminal I can see all the files. To print the output of log file you can use: cat /tmp/my_log_file.txt