# how to make xcode run a script before dependencies?

Tags: ios, xcode, build

Scenario:

I have `TargetA`, which is an iOS application. This app uses a static library, compiled by `TargetB`.
Obviously, `TargetB` is a dependency of `TargetA`, and `TargetB` is always built before `TargetA`. So far so good.

Now, I want a script to run `TargetA` is built, but **even before `TargetB`**.

### What I tried:

1. Adding a "setup" aggregate/external-build target, and making it a dependency of `TargetA`. It half works: Xcode runs `setup` and `TargetB` at the same time, so `TargetB` may get built too soon. Not good enough.
2. The same, but specifying in the scheme not to build in parallel. This works, but is a waste, since there are other targets that **can** be built in parallel.
3. Run the script in a `pre-action` build step inside the scheme. This works, but seems wrong (why? output from that step doesn't go into the build log; so perhaps I'm not meant to use it this way?).

### What I don't want to do:

Add the script as a dependency of `TargetB`. This would work; however, `TargetB` actually comes from another sub-project, and in the context of building it, parameters to the script are not yet known (mainly the root directory of `TargetA`'s project).

Am I missing anything, or do I have to settle for #2 or #3 above?

**EDIT:** in option #2 above, changing the order of dependencies (in my case, between `Setup` and `TargetB` does not help -- Xcode still selects the order arbitrarily.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Running the script as a `pre-action` build step inside the scheme is the best way to accomplish what you want. A common use of this approach is to adjust the project's build number base on the source control state ([example](http://yourhead.tumblr.com/post/49944504605/xcode-build-numbers-and-git-a-simple-solution-in)). As far as capturing the script output, unfortunately the only thing you can do is [redirect stdout for the script to a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723174/where-is-the-logfile-located-for-xcode-scheme-post-actions). That log file could be part of your project, so it would be easy to view from Xcode.

Comment: This did help me a lot, see a full setup here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450955/run-a-shell-script-before-build-in-xcode/29515958#29515958