# One different key between multiple Info.plist files per scheme?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, info.plist, xcode-scheme

My application's `Info.plist` file has around 20/30 keys inside. An external SDK we're implementing requires its app key to be set in the `Info.plist`, but requires separate keys for debug, enterprise distribution, and release schemes.

Is there a way I can create conditional additions to the `Info.plist` without having to maintain three duplicates of the file (and duplicate all of the other keys, which are identical across all targets)?

Basically what I'd like is the base `plist` exactly as it is now, then additional new `-Debug`, `-Distribution` and `Release` ones, which just contain this new key. What I'm trying to avoid is repetition of all keys, since it will make adding new ones in future a hassle.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different things you might try.

Xcode run script executed before app build
This is a script that is automatically executed before you build. Let's say the 3 duplicate plist files are called InfoA.plist, InfoB.plist and InfoC.plist which are all exact duplicate. When you build the project the contents of InfoA.plist are duplicated to InfoB.plist and InfoC.plist. This would require some knowledge of writing a shell script to do that, but the script is fairly simple.

You could duplicate and rename the files in the script. Or you could use command line tools to copy the contents of the main file to the duplicate files. Two command line utilities you can use to modify the contents of plist files are plutil and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html. These links might help: [Add files to an Xcode project from a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371351/add-files-to-an-xcode-project-from-a-script),

Modify scheme and add pre-action
Your schemes also allow you to add pre-actions to your build and you can do the same as above, but have it configured as a pre-action instead of a build phase script.

Here are a few links that might help: [how to make xcode run a script before dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340823/how-to-make-xcode-run-a-script-before-dependencies), https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/build-process/, [Xcode: Running a script before every build that modifies source code directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976454/xcode-running-a-script-before-every-build-that-modifies-source-code-directly) but you could also google for “xcode run script before build” for more links.